# routing traffic from production server to honeypot

Tags: routes, virtual-machine, snort, network-security, honeypot

I'm trying to direct malicious traffic intended for my production server to my honeypot. I have 3 VMs for now : A router running with Snort in inline mode, a Production server(debian) and my kippo honeypot. I'm very new to this and I'm looking for ways to filter out bad UDP traffic and then route it to my honeypot. Any help will be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered configuring port forwarding at your NAT so that ports you are offering are directed to the legit server and everything else is forwarded to the honeypot?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer thank you for replying. I'm not sure if what I'm thinking is correct, but isn't an attack also possible on the ports that I'm offering?Is there a way to first filter out the traffic on those ports and then route the illegitimate traffic to the honeypot? I'm particulary interested in DoS/DDoS attacks.

Comment: Sure it is... but it will be more difficult to dynamically route that traffic to the honeypot.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer what are the possible options? Is it possible any way by using snort (using it on a VM that I created which acts as a router)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of a current project that does this, but "baitnswitch" is a much older project that sought to accomplish it.  You could certainly do something like the following, however:

- Snort runs (either inline or not), generating alerts
- A log analysis process watches for particular alerts or high priority alerts
- When a high priority alert is seen, an iptables rule is inserted that dynamically NATs the inbound packets from that source to your honeypot

None of this would be difficult.  The only warning that I will give you is that when your iptables firewall gets several thousand rules in it, your kernel will start to explode randomly.  It's a super good idea to periodically flush these rules out to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I did try my hands on baitnswitch, it somehow did not work for me. I got some errors and since it was an older project I had no way of asking my doubts from anyone. Being very new in this field means I am not always sure how things work, so I read and try to implement. I would definitely take up your advice and would read into how can I implement this in my project. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Upvotes are appreciated. :) If you run into specific issues implementing this, feel free to add a comment here as that's the most likely way to attract my attention; I don't look at the [snort] tag often.

Comment: Hey @DavidHoelzer , I was wondering if we can add custom iptable rules in fwsnort and psad? I know they can accept and reject packets when they match the ruleset but can it also forward packets to a honeypot?